# Spring Boot Test cannot resolve repository dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I have one UserRepository which is a CRUD repository as shown:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

one UserController like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;
    @Autowired
    private UserResourceAssembler assembler;
```

and one WebMvcTest class to test my UserController:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
public class UserControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mvc;

  @Test
  public void getAllEmployeesAPI() throws Exception
  {
    mvc.perform( MockMvcRequestBuilders
        .get("/api/users")
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
  }

}
```

**When I run the server everything is fine. However I get this error when I run maven-test**:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>   Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean
>   '(inner bean)#7ba1cdbe' of type
>   [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting
>   bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7ba1cdbe': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor
>   argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean
>   '(inner bean)#7ba1cdbe' of type
>   [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting
>   bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7ba1cdbe': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor
>   argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7ba1cdbe': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor
>   argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the same structure now, i recommend `@SpringBootTest`.

`@WebMvcTest` does not load database-related beans into the application context.

Comment: I am getting this error this time: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc' available

Comment: I have solved this issue by adding @AutoConfigureMockMvc.

Answer (score 2):

`@WebMvcTest` loads just the Web layer. If it contains some dependencies, you need to load your application context as well. You could narrow the dependencies used only in your controller with the `@ContextConfiguration(classes = {YouTestConfiguration.class})`

Comment: Using @SpringBootTest only looks easier. Why should I struggle with the dependencies one by one?

Comment: The @ContextConfiguration gives you more grained control on the dependencies you use for the specific test. You could use it for loading only required dependencies.